# Is there a way to print using format string '9,999,999,999.999' in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm looking to get something like this in Python 2.7:

```
>>> print  "'?format?'" % 4333.22
'          4,333.220'
```

I'm not looking to print

```
'4333.220'
```

I need it to fill missing numbers to the length of the format `and` add commas from the format `'9,999,999,999.999'`:

```
'          4,333.220'
```

**Test:**

```
>>> print "{:,}".format(4200.2).rjust(15)
       4,200.2
```

I need:

```
'           4,200.200'
```

Comment: You already asked this exact same question. Why are you asking it again?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179564/is-there-a-way-to-print-using-format-string-9-999-999-99-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to print using format string '9,999,999.99' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179564/is-there-a-way-to-print-using-format-string-9-999-999-99-in-python)

Comment: You should edit your original question rather than posting a new one.

Comment: The error from your snippets suggests you're trying to use `print` as a statement in Python 3. I've pasted the code I posted below into Python prompts 2.7.13 and 3.5.3 verbatim, and the result is an appropriately formatted string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `format` to add commas and specify decimal width, and `rjust` to justify the output:

```
"{:,.3f}".format(4200.2).rjust(15)
```

Which results in:

```
'      4,200.200'
```

---

Referring to https://pyformat.info/, I see that it's also possible to specify the overall width in the format specifier. If the padded width you require is constant and known up-front, you can skip the `rjust` and simply use:

```
"{:15,.3f}".format(4200.2)
```

Comment: @olekb What version of Python are you using? Works fine for me in Python 3.5, and in fact should work in 2.7 as well.

Comment: @olekb You already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179564/is-there-a-way-to-print-using-format-string-9-999-999-99-in-python) and it was already flagged as a duplicate. Do not make duplicate questions, please.

Comment: @idjaw Well there's the additional question about padding the output that isn't present in the other question.

Comment: @idjaw how is it duplicate? where is the answer to this exact question?

Comment: I asked you which version of Python you're using. These random snippets do not answer the question.

Comment: @olekb Next time make sure your *original* question properly differs from having to have almost identical questions. Also, providing your own code attempts with error messages in the question and not in the comments will help as well to avoid constant back and forth and unnecessary confusion. Or even, your original question should have included what you were actually looking to do.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Integer part ok, but I do not see fractional that I need to control too

Comment: @olekb You can add the decimal width specifer to the existing format specifier: `{:,.3f}`. I'll add this to the answer.